# Woocommerce: remove 'add to cart' button in function.php

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to remove 'add to cart' button in **function.php**. Not using css.

I found this code, but it doesn't work. No error, nothing.

**code**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line worked for me. The second line don't, but with a little research it worked.
This is the code that worked for me. Both in loop and product page. My test page has WC 3.5.4 with Storefront Theme

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
```